# AWS: free 3rd level DNS name to access EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

When I start EC2 instance it receives public new DNS name like ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com.

Problem is this name is simply a shortcut for xx.xx.xx.xx, and it changes upon next instance restart. This means I need to update this name in my scripts.

Is there a way to assign a meaningful name for an instance, so that it will work as normal DNS name and survive server restarts? For example
my-site1-instance.compute-1.amazonaws.com.

Route 53 is good for public DNS names like site1.com but you have to pay for each name. I would be happily satisfied with a free 3rd level domains.

Comment: a domain name is $10/year, route53 will cost just over $6/year, and that's out of your league? Just use a local `hosts` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could install a no-ip.com client on the instance and have it update a hostname at no-ip.com (or any other dynamic dns service).

An alternative would be to assign an EIP to the instance which is free if the instance is running and costs a little ($0.005/h) if the instance is down.

This way you can setup a DNS A record wherever you have your domains configured already.

Comment: BTW: Route53 isn't exactly pricey. I go with using a subdomain that I delegate to Route53.

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I did. Thanks!